# "be quiet so that we could start the lesson" – why "could" and not "can"?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

The teacher said

> Stop talking and be quiet so that we could start the lesson.

Could you tell me why did the teacher use could. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly, that would be almost right if it was reported speech - *the teacher said to stop talking and be quiet so that we could start the lesson* - because reported speech has time based on the surrounding text, thus modals (as with other verbs) shift into the past (in this case).

Comment: Sounds to me like the teacher slightly changed their mind about what they were going to say. In other words, if they had a second chance, I don't think they would have said the same thing. Is this teacher a native speaker?

Answer (score 2):

**Could** is more polite than **can**, but I don't recall the last time I heard someone use it in a sentence like yours.

I would almost always expect to hear:

> Stop talking and be quiet so (that) we can start the lesson.